# Search option in jQuery datatables

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery data table in my site. I have integrated the "Multi-tab" functionality and "Ajax Content loading" functionality with the datatables. Now I want to integrate the search option in my data table. My coding is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({   // My datatable Div Id
                "show": function(event, ui) {
                    var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
                    if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
                        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#example1').dataTable({     //example1->My first table Id
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "test_data.php",    // "test_data.php" provides content for my first table
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });

            $('#example2').dataTable({    // example2->My second table Id
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "test_data2.php",     // "test_data2.php" provides content for my second table
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
});
```

I found in the "Examples of Data table" for the solution of searching option. That coding is:

```
var asInitVals = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
                }
            });

            $("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
                /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
                oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
            });



            /*
             * Support functions to provide a little bit of 'user friendlyness' to the textboxes in 
             * the footer
             */
            $("tfoot input").each( function (i) {
                asInitVals[i] = this.value;
            });

            $("tfoot input").focus( function () {
                if ( this.className == "search_init" )
                {
                    this.className = "";
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });

            $("tfoot input").blur( function (i) {
                if ( this.value == "" )
                {
                    this.className = "search_init";
                    this.value = asInitVals[$("tfoot input").index(this)];
                }
            });

        });
```

Please guide me to integrate the above solution in my code otherwise please give your suggestion to integrate the search option.

Answer (score 0):

This Example Code may helps you...

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
            <html>
                 <head>
                      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

                      <title>Working on Datatable</title>

                      <!-- Your JQuery Library -->
                      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

                      <!-- Your DataTable library -->
                      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                           $(document).ready(function()
                           {
                                $('#userlist').dataTable({
                                     "sDom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
                                });

                           } );
                      </script>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                      <div class="box">
                           <div style="width:100%;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="userlist" width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #0000CC; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
                                     <thead>
                                          <tr style=" background-color:#004677; font-size:14px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold;" height="30">
                                               <th>Slno</th>
                                               <th>User ID</th>
                                               <th>Name</th>
                                               <th>Email</th>
                                               <th>City</th>
                                               <th>Contact Number</th>
                                          </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody>
                                         <tr>
                                             <td>1</td>
                                             <td>0001</td>
                                             <td>Hearaman</td>
                                             <td>hearaman.dev@gmail.com</td>
                                             <td>Bangalore,India</td>
                                             <td>9740798429</td>
                                         </tr>

                                         <tr>
                                             <td>2</td>
                                             <td>0002</td>
                                             <td>Raman</td>
                                             <td>raman@gmail.com</td>
                                             <td>Hyderabad,India</td>
                                             <td>886798429</td>
                                         </tr>

                                         <tr>
                                             <td>3</td>
                                             <td>0003</td>
                                             <td>Satish Chandra</td>
                                             <td>satishchandra.surampudi@gmail.com</td>
                                             <td>Bangalore,India</td>
                                             <td>948209876</td>
                                         </tr>

                                         <tr>
                                             <td>4</td>
                                             <td>0004</td>
                                             <td>satish</td>
                                             <td>satish@gmail.com</td>
                                             <td>Bangalore,India</td>
                                             <td>987639029</td>
                                         </tr>
                                     </tbody>
                                </table>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                 </body>
            </html>
```

To Download DataTable plug-in and to see more examples, Visit http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Ok as far as i get it. Add filter option searching i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#example1').dataTable({     //example1->My first table Id
            "bProcessing": true,
```

> "searching" : true,

```
            "sAjaxSource": "test_data.php",    // "test_data.php" provides content for my first table
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });

        $('#example2').dataTable({    // example2->My second table Id
            "bProcessing": true,
            "searching": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "test_data2.php",     // "test_data2.php" provides content for my second table
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
```

});